# Left float problems

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hi
I am trying to make a phone sort-of looking app. But the apps on the phone aren't going next to each other. I used `float:left`, but that didn't work. Maybe I have to add `position:relative` for it to work, but I don't know why. Any help is very much appreciated.
[Link to code](http://codepen.io/chroline/pen/qErJWQ)

Comment: What do you mean by `sort-of lookig app`? What are you trying to achieve? It's not very clear to me.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are having problems?

Comment: no idea about you are really talking about, but probably you need to put the elements as display:block and give them some size to float them

Comment: @hugohabel Sorry about that. Here's the link:[link to code](http://codepen.io/chroline/pen/qErJWQ)

Comment: @Guillermo A iPhone looking app, sort of one that has apps left to right and looks like a new iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `clear: both` from your `message` class.